# MS-Access 2007: One-to-one relationship in form, not showing all records

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, one-to-one, relationships

helpful folk of the internet.

Background info about the data:
I work for a research station and we spend part of the summer live trapping mammals. Occasionally an animal dies in the trap and we retain it to send to a museum.

I'm making a database for our mammal trapping data. We have a table for captures which contains the following fields:

- CaptureID (unique identifier for each capture & primary key)
- MammalID (identifier for each mammal so we can track recaptures across days & sites)
- SurveyID (links back to tables w/ site & date information)
- A bunch of fields about different measurements we take everytime we capture a mammals
- Dead? (Says "Y" if the animal was dead, "N" if the animal was alive)
- CatNum (unique id for each sample. This is assigned to the dead animals when we collect them and used to keep the specimens linked to their data as well as track them as they move through our collections & to other museums)

Here's my problem. We'd really like to have a separate table for our Mort Samples where everything is identified by a catnum and then has info about where the sample is and other info we get back from museums when we send them samples. I want to link this table to the capture table using either Catnum or capture id. I want them in separate tables because they're different kinds of data.

I'm currently using capture id as the link in this One-to-One because not every capture id has a catnum and so I can't link the primary key from MortTable to a field with null values.

Here's my problem.

In an ideal world we would be able to let anyone enter this data. So we made an easy to use form that looks very similar to our data sheet, with Capture Table being a sub-form in table form under the info about site & date and such.

On the data form there's a space for catnum, and it's currently a field in the capture table and on the capture sub-form. I want to make it so that entering a value in "catnum" on this form creates that primary key in another table.

I've tried doing this with an "AfterUpdate" (though I may have done that wrong), and by replacing the catnum from the capture table with the one from the mort table (and I would ultimately remove the catnum field from the capture table if this works). This last solution sort of works. In that it lets me do what I want, but means I can only display captures where the animal died on the form (since the others have no catnum associated with them and don't show up).

Is there a better way to do this without

- Restricting which records are displayed on this general form?
- Requiring potentially wildcard seasonal employees to leave this general form that looks exactly like what is in their hands and... GASP! ask them to do something strange and different.

We'd really rather just have the catnum records created automatically during data entry & then let one of the collections people go back and fill in the collection info than have the field crews leave the basic form to do it or have the collections people generate an entirely new list at the risk of missing something.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a unique auto number for your capture table, and a unique auto number for your mort table. Add a column in the mort table for the primary key of the capture table. This will be a foreign key. Since your tables are joined by the primary key in the capture table and a foreign key in the mort table, you wouldn't need to include the catNum in the mort table as it is easily accessible by query. (bad idea to duplicate data anyway.)  Your users would still be able to search and maintain records by CatNum.  Manually creating  a PK always turns out bad in the long run

Comment: Either way once this is done the catnum from capture table will be removed, taking care of the redundancy issue. As for manual vs autonumber, that doesn't matter too much in terms of what I want to do (I could easily switch it to autonumber & just set the catnum to no duplicates). But either way, won't the entry form still only display capture records that have an entry in the mort table? That's my issue, displaying all capture records regardless of whether there is matching data in the linked table.

Comment: As long as you are using an outer or Left join on your mort table, it shouldn't limit the results of your capture table. That's why you use a primary key that is not your CatNum. You can delete the CatNum, but the relationship still exists due to the PK and FK relationship.  Using a Left Join on your Mort Table ensure that you get all the records from your Capture table and any records in the Mort table that have a matching Pk and FK.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've never had to use right or left joins before, so I didn't realize they would solve my problem!